# programmatically retrieve security constraints from web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, security

Is there any possiblity to obtain the list of constraints from web.xml ?

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

Even better is there a programmatic way to add new constraints ?

Thanks,
Victor

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/follow_up_on_servlet_3 and this: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kumarjayanti/archive/2009/12/24/using-servletsecurity-annotation-javaee-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `ServletContainerInitializer`, in its `onStartup()` method, you would basically do what your container does when it parses your web.xml. For example:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> classes, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = ctx.addServlet("myServlet", "com.package.myServlet"); // loop through classes set to find all your servlets
    HttpConstraintElement constraint = new HttpConstraintElement(); // many constructors with options
    ServletSecurityElement securityElement = new ServletSecurityElement(constraint); // many different constructors
    servlet.setServletSecurity(securityElement);
}
```

There are a lot of options in the constructors I've commented for all sorts of configurations, even through the servlet 3.0 [security annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/follow_up_on_servlet_3). I'll let you discover them all.

As for adding new constraints after initialization, the javadoc for [`setServletSecurity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.Dynamic.html#setServletSecurity%28javax.servlet.ServletSecurityElement%29) says:

```
* @throws IllegalStateException if the {@link ServletContext} from
* which this <code>ServletRegistration</code> was obtained has
* already been initialized
```

I couldn't find anything for obtaining a list of constraints through `ServletContext` interface, but you can always parse the web.xml yourself.

Comment: I wouldn't want to go with a solution which requires straying away to much from the std, but the `ServletContainerInitializer` sounds good. I've seen here ( http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/03/using-servlets-3-0-servletcontainerinitializer/ ) that I can even embed it in my web app. Good solution I will try it on to see if it fits :)

Comment: @victor Your container will first check your `META-INF/services` for a file containing the full class name of your class that implements [ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html). You're not limited to just that. You can also have, in parallel, your web.xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Servlet 3.0 on Annotations and Deployment descriptors](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html#annotations-vs-deployment-descriptor) there is no mention of adding new `security-constraints` programatically. So, I doubt if you can add security contraints programatically.