# How to retrieve permissions from web.xml

Tags: java, web.xml, jaas, jacc

I would like to know if there is a better way (without reflection) to get the java.security.Permissions for a specific URL and Role.

for example:

```
 boolean canAccess = SecurityController.isAllowedToAccessUrl("/pages/confirmOrders.action", Collections.singletonList(new UserPrincipal("Dave")));
```

would work with the following constraint (web.xml):

```
<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/pages/confirmOrders.action</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>Dave</role-name>
 </auth-constraint>
```

The code, I wrote bellow works well. What I don't like is that I have to use reflection to invoke getContextPolicy from DelegatingPolicy.getInstance() and invoke getPermissionsForRole from ContextPolicy.

```
import org.jboss.security.jacc.ContextPolicy;
import org.jboss.security.jacc.DelegatingPolicy;

import javax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory;
import javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext;
import javax.security.jacc.PolicyContextException;
import javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SecurityController {
  private static final Logger LOG  = Logger.getLogger(SecurityController.class.getName());

  static boolean isAllowedToAccessUrl(final String url, final List<Principal> principalRoles) {
    initializeConfigurationInService();

    boolean result = false;
    for (Principal principalRole : principalRoles) {
      try{
        final ContextPolicy contextPolicy = getContextPolicy();
        final Permissions permissions = getPermissionsFromContextPolicy(contextPolicy, principalRole.getName());
        result |= permissions.implies(new WebResourcePermission(url, new String[] {"GET","POST"}));
      }catch (Exception e){
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "checkAllowed failed checking if : ", e);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private static void initializeConfigurationInService() {
    try {
      final PolicyConfigurationFactory policyConfigurationFactory = PolicyConfigurationFactory.getPolicyConfigurationFactory();
      policyConfigurationFactory.getPolicyConfiguration(PolicyContext.getContextID(), false);
    } catch (PolicyContextException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      LOG.log(Level.INFO, "initializeConfigurationInService", e);
    }
  }

  private static Permissions getPermissionsFromContextPolicy(ContextPolicy contextPolicy, String loginName) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    final Method getPermissionsForRole = contextPolicy.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getPermissionsForRole", String.class);
    getPermissionsForRole.setAccessible(true);
    return (Permissions) getPermissionsForRole.invoke(contextPolicy, loginName);
  }


  private static ContextPolicy getContextPolicy() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    final DelegatingPolicy delegatingPolicy = DelegatingPolicy.getInstance();
    final Method getContextPolicy = delegatingPolicy.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getContextPolicy", String.class);
    getContextPolicy.setAccessible(true);
    return (ContextPolicy) getContextPolicy.invoke(delegatingPolicy, PolicyContext.getContextID());
  }
}
```

I read [programmatically retrieve security constraints from web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733946/programmatically-retrieve-security-constraints-from-web-xml) but found it not very useful.

Any comments, ideas are really welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I've given a portable/pure JACC example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344117/how-to-get-user-roles-in-a-jsp-servlet/48499806#48499806).

Answer (score 3):

A similar standard method to do the 'isAllowedToAccessUrl` function is available in Java EE 8.

```
boolean hasAccessToWebResource(String resource, String... methods)
```

> Checks whether the caller has access to the provided "web resource"
>   using the given methods, as specified by section 13.8 of the Servlet
>   specification. A caller has access if the web resource is either not
>   protected (constrained), or when it is protected by a role and the
>   caller is in that role.

See: [SecurityContext#hasAccessToWebResource](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/security/enterprise/SecurityContext.html#hasAccessToWebResource-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of [Uux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986374/uux) I was able to shorten my code and get rid of using reflection. I am now able to verify if a specific role is allowed to access a specific URL in my code.

workable code below:

```
import javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SecurityController {
  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SecurityController.class.getName());

  static boolean isAllowedToAccessUrl(final String url, final List<Principal> principalRoles) {
    try {
      final CodeSource codesource = new CodeSource(null, (Certificate[]) null);
      final Principal[] principals = principalRoles.toArray(new Principal[0]);
      final ProtectionDomain domain = new ProtectionDomain(codesource, null, null, principals);
      return Policy.getPolicy().implies(domain, (new WebResourcePermission(url, new String[] {"GET", "POST"})));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "checkAllowed failed checking if : ", e);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```